# Python and HTML: parsing away tags

Tags: python, html, tags

Let's say you've been able to store part of an HTML file into a string called 'source', that looks like this (it can even start off with a closing `</...>` tag):

```
</div> <div class = "label" xml: ... other_parameters: ... > Some plain english here </div> </div> Some more english text... <some more tags> more english... etc
```

How does one go about extracting just the first "Some plain english here" (and only that), from that line, with no whitespace or newline markers right before the first letter in "Some" nor right after the last letter in "here"?

[EDIT] Extraction into a new string would be fine

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of XML/HTML parsers to choose from, most popular are:

- [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)
- [xml.dom.minidom](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html)
- [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)
- [lxml](http://lxml.de/)

Using `ElementTree`:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.fromstring("""
<body>
    <div class="label"> Some plain english here </div>
</body>""")
print tree.find('.//div[@class="label"]').text.strip()
```

Using `lxml`:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.fromstring("""
<body>
    <div class="label"> Some plain english here </div>
</body>""")
print tree.find('.//div[@class="label"]').text.strip()
```

Using `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<body>
    <div class="label"> Some plain english here </div>
</body>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print soup.find('div', class_="label").text.strip()
```

No example for `minidom`, sorry, don't use it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: hey @alecxe - I've made an edit to the original question to make it more clear what's being intended. thanks for your response, but would you mind taking another look?

Comment: @giver it's a bit unclear what do you want to extract, give me a real part of an html please.

Comment: it's pretty much just the first occurrence of genuine non-tag English text.

Comment: the code area in the above question was edited to allow for a pattern of </tags... > english <tags...> more english <more tags...> more english, etc <etc>

Comment: I was only looking for the first occurrence "english", and anything after that can be discarded

Comment: It doesn't sound difficult at all, just provide a simple real-world example - it will help me to help you. Thanks.

Comment: I'll probably try to use BeautifulSoup, so if that example could be a little more expanded upon, that would be really helpful

Comment: </div> <div class = "label" xml:lang="sp" lang="sp" a-few-more-paramters="..."> To be extracted </div> </div> To be ignored <some more tags (to ignore as well) > To be ignored, etc <some more tags (to ignore as well) >

Comment: ^ Could you show me how to extract just "To be extracted" from the example above, preferably with beautiful soup?

Comment: I didn't specify what those tags were, since they could literally be anything throughout the file. Thanks

Comment: @giver The code I've provided works for the example you are showing. Basically it parses the contents of a `div` with `class` attribute equals to "label". Then it strips the text which helps to emit all the leading and trimming spaces.

Comment: Lastly, do you know how one should get around this error: "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc0' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
" when trying to write the stripped text to a file? Thanks.

Comment: @giver try to call `.encode('utf8')` on the text you are writing.

Comment: Let's say that we want to write the string "A vienna" (with a special-character marking over the "A" that looks somewhat like a tilde, to the file. Is there a way to make sure it just prints "vienna"? (removed letter, and removed space)

Comment: just saw your most recent comment. I'll give that a try, too